# Laravel/Bootstrap 5 - Making a card row shrinks its image

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap's 5 card and Laravel to make a car card. When I try to make a row with cards, the image shrinks. If I remove the "row" class, its image fits perfectly. ¿How can I solve this issue?

````
        <h1>Vehículos</h1>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($autos as $auto)    
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; border-radius: 25px;">
                <a href="{{ URL('auto/'.$auto->id)}}">
                    <img src="{{ URL('images/'.$auto->foto)}}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="border-top-right-radius: 25px; border-top-left-radius: 25px;">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{$auto->marca." ".$auto->modelo}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        Año: {{$auto->año}}
                        Kilometros: {{$auto->kilometros}}
                            Motor: {{$auto->motor}}
                            Combustible: {{$auto->combustible}}
                            Precio: $ {{$auto->precio}}
                        </p>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div> ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TviHn.png
````

Comment: add ```img-fluid``` class to your image

Comment: I tried `class="card-img-top img-fluid"` but it didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reproduce the error on my own end and I found the issue. When using a `bootstrap row` , you have to add columns using the `col` class. So change your code to this

```
<h1>Vehículos</h1>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($autos as $auto)   
            <div class="col"> 
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; border-radius: 25px;">
                <a href="{{ URL('auto/'.$auto->id)}}">
                    <img src="{{ URL('images/'.$auto->foto)}}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="border-top-right-radius: 25px; border-top-left-radius: 25px;">
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{$auto->marca." ".$auto->modelo}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        Año: {{$auto->año}}
                        Kilometros: {{$auto->kilometros}}
                            Motor: {{$auto->motor}}
                            Combustible: {{$auto->combustible}}
                            Precio: $ {{$auto->precio}}
                        </p>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

This would fix the issue of the image being shrinked.

[image: check image]

**SIDENOTE:** Do note that the bootstrap `col` class has prefixes to make it adapt to different screens. You can check out [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! The `col` class did the trick. BTW, did you wirte `row` instead of `col` in the answer code? I tried that and changed it to `col` because it stayed the same.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to write ```col``` not ```row```. I have edited my answer.